# Is vertical scrolling in layouts suppressed when used in a GridViewPager in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

In my Android Wear app I'm using a GridViewPager to display two layouts side by side that you can swipe between horizontally.  One page has a ScrollView and sub-elements. The other page has a BoxInsetLayout and FrameLayout for a WearableListView.  If I display each page by itself without the GridViewPager I can scroll the text in the ScrollView just fine and I can scroll the list of items in the WearableListView just fine.  But when I put the two pages together in the GridViewPager I can't scroll the elements in either one up or down at least not on my Moto360.  The ScrollView does scroll vertically in the round Android emulator but not the WearableListView.

Either I'm doing something wrong or it's not meant to work that way.

My main java class has:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear);

    GridViewPager pager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_wear_pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new gridViewPagerAdapter());

    DotsPageIndicator dotsPageIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.activity_wear_page_indicator);
    dotsPageIndicator.setPager(pager);
}
private class gridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int arg0) { return 2; }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { return 1; }

    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col) {
        View view = null;

        if (col == 0) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.read_page_round, container, false);
            mTextView = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
        else {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.find_page_round, container, false);
            listView =  (WearableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.wearable_list);
            listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), elements));
            listView.setClickListener(WearApplication.this);
        }

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }
}
```

activity_wear.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
        android:id="@+id/activity_wear_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"/>

    <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/activity_wear_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">
    </android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator>
</FrameLayout>
```

read_page_round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".WearApplication"
tools:deviceIds="wear_round">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="@style/wear_main_text"/>

    (Other TextView items)

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

find_page_round.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Select List"
        style="@style/wear_main_app"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="left|bottom|right">
        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:id="@+id/wearable_list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I just got the same issue and managed to get around it (however it's not that beautiful).

So here was my problem:
I have a view which contains both a DotsPageIndicator and a GridViewPager. At first everything was bundled in a RelativeLayout. But in one of my GridViewPager pages I wanted to use the BoxInsetLayout. However according to several StackOverflow answers I came across the BoxInsetLayout needs to be the root element of your activity. So then I bundled my DotsPageIndicator and GridViewPager together in the BoxInsetLayout, but if would then apply the insets (app:layout_box="all") on one of my GridViewPager child's it wouldn't work...

Why it doesn't work:
I somehow stupid to only allow a BoxInsetLayout as the root view of an Activity... However that's the rule so we have to work with it. But then it als seems that you cannot apply the inset rules on any level of view, only on the views just one level down the BoxInsetLayout. So in my case that would mean that I can only apply the insets to the DotsPageIndicator and GridViewPager. And that's not what I want.

How to work around this limitation:
So here is how I worked around this limitation in my layout file:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                              android:background="@drawable/balance_detail_background_full">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="all"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/dummy_view"/>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

        <be.belfius.directmobile.android.wearable.widget.FixedGridViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

So for the first part you can see that I added a 'dummy' view with transparant background that sets the BoxInsetLayout to give me a nice square view on a perfectly round watch. However in the ViewPager child views this will not affect anything.
But what I did next is to pass that view from my activity, through my ViewPagerAdapter (in my case a SingleRowGridPagerAdapter) to my child views.

So in code that would that my onCreate(..) method would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    View dummyBoxInsetView = findViewById(R.id.dummy_view);
    mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mViewPagerIndicator = findViewById(R.id.view_pager_indicator);
    mAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(YOUR_PARAMS, dummyBoxInsetView);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPagerIndicator.setPager(mViewPager);
}
```

In your custom view pager you would initialise all your child views (pages) and for the pages you want you can do something like this:

```
public void setReferenceBoxInsetLayoutView(View boxInsetLayoutView) {
    int inboxOffsetLeft = boxInsetLayoutView.getPaddingLeft();
    int inboxOffsetRight = boxInsetLayoutView.getPaddingRight();
    int inboxOffsetTop = boxInsetLayoutView.getPaddingTop();
    int inboxOffsetBottom = boxInsetLayoutView.getPaddingBottom();

    MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) mViewThatNeedsOffsets.getLayoutParams();
    marginLayoutParams.leftMargin = inboxOffsetLeft;
    marginLayoutParams.rightMargin = inboxOffsetRight;
    marginLayoutParams.topMargin = inboxOffsetTop;
    marginLayoutParams.bottomMargin = inboxOffsetBottom;
    mViewThatNeedsOffsets.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);
}
```

So as you can see the offset you need for your view is set on the reference view by the BoxInsetLayout as margins. If you only need left and right, or top and bottom, or even one feel free... It's all in yours hands now.

I know it's a dirty solution but it's the best so far, after searching for quite a few hours, to get things done the way we want for round watches.

To improve performance you can set the dummy view's (aka dummyBoxInsetView) visibility to 'invisible' in the layout file. That way it still gets measured but not drawn. Didn't test visiblity="gone" but I suppose that would not work as the view would not get measured anymore.